# Regex pattern error on API 21(android 5) and below

Tags: java, android, regex, kotlin, android-5.0-lollipop

Android 5 and below getting error from my regex pattern on runtime:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:
(?<g1>(http|ftp)(s)?://)?(?<g2>[\w-:@])+(?<TLD>\.[\w\-]+)+(:\d+)?((|\?)([\w\-._~:/?#\[\]@!$&'()*+,;=.%])*)*
```

Here is code sample:

```
val urlRegex = "(?<g1>(http|ftp)(s)?://)?(?<g2>[\\w-:@])+(?<TLD>\\.[\\w\\-]+)+(:\\d+)?((|\\?)([\\w\\-._~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;=.%])*)*"
val sampleUrl = "https://www.google.com"
val urlMatchers = Pattern.compile(urlRegex).matcher(sampleUrl)
assert(urlMatchers.find())
```

This pattern works really fine on all APIs above 21.

Comment: Not heard of a regex being API dependant! This is interesting. Have you tried using the kotlin library for this? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/index.html

Comment: Yes! but unfortunately i got the same error.  @user8159708

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the earlier versions do not support named groups. As per this source, the [named groups were introduced in Kotlin 1.2](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/e81859b50df0f8c33d1711d797bfcc36b459d6e3/libraries/stdlib/jdk8/src/kotlin/text/RegexExtensions.kt). Remove them if you do not need those submatches and only use the regex for validation.

Your regex is very inefficient as it contains a lot of nested quantified groups. See a "cleaner" version of it below.

Also, it seems you want to check if there is a regex match inside your input string. Use [`Regex#containsMatchIn()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/contains-match-in.html):

```
val urlRegex = "(?:(?:http|ftp)s?://)?[\\w:@.-]+\\.[\\w-]+(?::\\d+)?\\??[\\w.~:/?#\\[\\]@!$&'()*+,;=.%-]*"
val sampleUrl = "https://www.google.com"
val urlMatchers = Regex(urlRegex).containsMatchIn(sampleUrl)
println(urlMatchers) // => true
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/JHJGY88380) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4OLAkT/1).

If you need to check the whole string match  use `matches`:

```
Regex(urlRegex).matches(sampleUrl)
```

See [another Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/EXLEFM6119).

Note that to define a regex, you need to use the `Regex` class constructor.

Comment: The problem is when it want to compile the regex pattern it throws `PatternSyntaxException` on api 21 and below. It doesn't matter that i use java `Pattern` class or kotlin `Regex` class, it throws the same exception.

Comment: @Alireza Your pattern was not quite optimal, see updated pattern in the answer.

Comment: @Alireza as Wiktor said: try your regex on https://regex101.com/r/WbLlCf/1/ it also suggest some improvements like the backslashes before an unescaped delimiter

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I replaced the regex pattern with you'r optimized pattern in my code but unfortunately i got the same error.

Comment: @Alireza Does it support named groups? Do you need them at all? Remove all `?<...>`s from the pattern (`?<g1>`, `?<g2>`, `?<g3>`, `?<TLD>`).

Comment: @a2hur I tried that and it didn't fix. I mentioned that this pattern works really fine on android API 22 and above, but it doesn't compile on Android API 21 and below

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew We use this pattern for checking URLs in our back-end API. and everything works fine.

Comment: @Alireza No, it is not good and once someone uses [the string like here](https://regex101.com/r/bGblqV/1), your app will crash (if you use `matches` with your pattern, I see no point using `find` to validate).

Comment: @a2hur Thank's man i removed the groups that you mentioned and it worked.